# How to ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE to colums that contains more characters than default

Tags: mysql, constraints, alter

I want to add unique to the columns that is title, language and download (3 columns). Since i don't have other options to get rid of duplicate entries. Here is the code:

```
ALTER TABLE datapdf ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (title, language, download);
```

But i get this error:

## 1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Is there any solution for this? But remember, it should match by this three columns.

Comment: Add a fourth column. Save the hash of the 3 columns combined (you can 'glue' them like a string and hash). Make the column unique. Job done, length is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your this three columns' length are too long,I have do a test,look at it.

```
drop table if exists datapdf;
create table datapdf 
(
title varchar(200),
 language varchar(300), 
 download varchar(510)
);

ALTER TABLE datapdf ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (title, language, download);
```

I get an error the as same as your.

```
Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

But if I change the structure of table `datapdf`,it runs succeed.

```
drop table if exists datapdf;
create table datapdf 
(
title varchar(100),
 language varchar(100), 
 download varchar(100)
);

ALTER TABLE datapdf ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (title, language, download);
```

This is the `Action`.

```
ALTER TABLE datapdf ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (title, language, download)
```

So I think you can change your table's structure(if possible) to solve this problem.**However**,it's not a good solution,because you may lose your data.One of the best solution is what @N.B said(the first comment of this question):"
Add a fourth column. Save the hash of the 3 columns combined. Make the column unique."

Comment: Thanks it is worthy.

Comment: Well, this answer is wrong sadly. You can't change the length of columns only so they can fit into unique constraint. What happens if I have textual columns and if I have 20 other columns that combined yield something unique? Should I obliterate their length and lose my data or should I come up with something smarter? I don't mind if you take my first comment and add it to the answer. This way, you're going to mislead future visitors who will think that they need to alter their data structure - and they don't.

Comment: @N.B.: I have read your comment ,you are right! Save the hash of the 3 columns combined is a vary good solution.I will edit my answer.Thank you very much!!!